# Cannot set thread_pool setting in Elastic Cloud user settings

Tags: elasticsearch, threadpool

Using ES `v6.4.3`

I'm getting a bunch of TransportService errors when writing a high volume of transactions. The exact error is:

```
StatusCodeError: 429 - {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"remote_transport_exception","reason":"[instance-0000000002][10.44.0.71:19428][indices:data/write/bulk[s][p]]"}],"type":"es_rejected_execution_exception","reason":"rejected execution of org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$7@35110df8 on EsThreadPoolExecutor[name = instance-0000000002/write, queue capacity = 200, org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsThreadPoolExecutor@3fd60b4f[Running, pool size = 2, active threads = 2, queued tasks = 200, completed tasks = 1705133]]"},"status":429}
```

The general consensus seems to be bumping the queue_size so requests don't get dropped. As you can see in the error my queue_size is the default 200, and filled up. (I know simple bumping the queue_size is not a magic solution, but this is exactly what I need in this case)

So following [this doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-enterprise/current/ece-add-user-settings.html#ece-add-user-settings) on how to change the elasticsearch.yml setting I try to add the queue_size bump here:
[image]

```
thread_pool.write.queue_size: 2000
```

And when I save I get this error: 
[image]

```
'thread_pool.write.queue_size': is not allowed
```

I understand the user override settings blacklist certain settings, so if my problem is truly that `thread_pool.write.queue_size` is blacklisted, how can I access my elasticsearch.yml file to change it?

Thank you!

Comment: You cannot. Increasing the queue size is a [bad practice and discouraged](https://www.elastic.co/blog/why-am-i-seeing-bulk-rejections-in-my-elasticsearch-cluster) (which is the reason why the setting is blacklisted in the first place). You should either consider throttling your client or (temporarily) add nodes to your cluster.